# Is it possible to make python ForwardRef lazy?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I'm trying to use pydantic with an object that has subclasses. I have the following code that works, but I don't really like the cumbersome hiding mechanic. This is just a prototype of what I plan to do over several modules with many more classes subclassing the class that gets used in the upper class, etc. Therefore my question is:

Is there a way to force `ForwardRef` to be lazy?

Here's what I've got that works, I'd like to remove the _hide = ... bit.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class Thing2(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: Literal["Thing2"]

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        global T2_subclasses
        T2_subclasses = TypeVar("T2_subclasses", bound=Union[tuple(Thing2.__subclasses__())])

T2_subclasses = None

class Thing3(Thing2):
    b: Literal["Thing3"]

_hide = [T2_subclasses]
del T2_subclasses

class Thing(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    c: Union[Thing2, ForwardRef("T2_subclasses")]

T2_subclasses = _hide[0]

class Thing4(Thing2):
    b: Literal["Thing4"]

d = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "qwerty",
    "c": {
        "a": "zxcv",
        "b": "Thing4"
    },
}

c = Thing(**d)
print(c)
```

Edit: Found a workaround, though this still seems silly: Add a second ForwardRef after the class and chain it on:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class Thing2(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: Literal["Thing2"]

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        global T2_subclasses
        T2_subclasses = TypeVar("T2_subclasses", bound=Union[tuple(Thing2.__subclasses__())])

T2_subclasses = None

class Thing3(Thing2):
    b: Literal["Thing3"]

class Thing(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    c: Union[Thing2, ForwardRef("T2_subclasses_")]

T2_subclasses_ = ForwardRef("T2_subclasses")

class Thing4(Thing2):
    b: Literal["Thing4"]

d = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "qwerty",
    "c": {
        "a": "zxcv",
        "b": "Thing4"
    },
}

c = Thing(**d)
print(c)
```

P.S. This is actually required to cross modules, because ForwardRef just assumes that if the module is loaded it's done and won't wait if you don't have this (i.e. if `T2_subclasses` is in another module).

Comment: Have a look at pydantic determinated unions: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-str-discriminators

Comment: @YuriiMotov sure, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. However, this is going to be a set of models spanning multiple modules and I have no reasonable way of generating the list of classes to put in the Union. That's why I'm using .__subclasses__(). However, I need to make sure that this is done after all the imports are good and done. I don't see anything in the documentation to help me with that. If they have a builtin way of doing this please be more specific, because I'm missing it.

Comment: You *shouldn't be using `ForwardRef` at all*. A lot of these aren't even valid type annotations. Can you take a step back and explain what it is you are actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, well it seems to work the way that pydantic uses them. I do understand it's not the usual way to use it. What I want is for `c` in `Thing` to take `Thing2` or any subclass thereof. These subclasses will be defined all over the place and there is no way to create a list of all the types that exist at the point that the equivalent of `Thing` would be. Therefore this Union needs to be generated on the fly (which is what the code above does). I'm using the ForwardRef as a lazy evaluation because pydantic doesn't seem to have any other way to lazy evaluate.

Comment: My point is, everwhere you have `ForwardRef("SomeString")` can just be `"SomeString"`

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to try that. I suspect that the `T2_subclasses_ = ForwardRef("T2_subclasses")` will still be needed, but you might be right about the bit inside the `Union`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yurii Motov pointed out, I think the right approach is to use discriminated unions. Here is a minimal working example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal, Annotated, Union


class Pet(BaseModel):
    """Animal class"""
    name: str
    age: int
    

class Dog(Pet):
    """Dog class"""
    type: Literal["dog"] = "dog"
    breed: str


class Cat(Pet):
    """Cat class"""
    type: Literal["cat"] = "cat"
    breed: str

 
AnyPet = Annotated[Union[Dog, Cat], Field(discriminator="type")]


class Home(BaseModel):
    """Home class"""
    pet: AnyPet


data = {
    "pet": {
        "type": "dog",
        "name": "Buddy",
        "age": 4,
        "breed": "Golden Retriever"
    }
}

home = Home(**data)
print(home)
```

In one of your comments you mentioned:

> However, this is going to be a set of models spanning multiple modules and I have no reasonable way of generating the list of classes to put in the Union.

My recommendation would be to restructure your code to keep all the valid subclasses (all pets) in a single file / module and put the `AnyPet` type definition at the bottom as a registry of valid sub-classes. Or at least figure out the right import order. For example the `AnyPet` could live in an `__init__.py` in a hypothetical `pets` sub-module:

```bash
pets/
__init__.py
cats.py
dogs.py
```

Users will then only import the `AnyPet` type and get access to all sub-classes.

If you would like to auto-generate the `AnyPet` type you could consider a pattern along the lines of:

```py
valid_sub_classes = []

for sub_class in Pet.__subclasses__():
    field = sub_class.model_fields.get("type", None)

    if field is None:
        raise ValueError(f"{sub_class.__name__} is missing a 'type' field")

    valid_sub_classes.append(sub_class)

AnyPet = Annotated[Union[tuple(valid_sub_classes)], Field(discriminator="type")]
print(AnyPet)
```

This will automatically detect all the sub-classes of a given parent class and merge them into a union.

If your models are split across multiple sub-modules and you really cannot resolve this, I think the second best thing to do is to define a function that does a delayed execution of the code I showed above:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from my_module import get_any_pet

AnyPet = get_any_pet()

class Home(BaseModel):
    """Home class"""
    pet: AnyPet
```

I hope this helps!